# Office365 Unified Api - Share file with specific user and get file thumbnail

Tags: c#, api, rest, office365, office365api

I am trying to do the following two things:
- Share file with specific user
- Get thumbnail for a file

I am currently using the Office 365 Unified Api and I'd like to keep it that way if possible.

I thought it would be possible to get the thumbnails for a file like this:

```
"https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/files/" + id + "/thumbnails"
```

This returns the following error

```
{
  "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
  "message": "The expression drive/items/<id>/thumbnails is not valid."
}
```

As for the file sharing, I have no idea where to start. I hope someone can help me out with this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thumbnails feature is available in the v2 of the Files API - please refer to https://dev.onedrive.com/items/thumbnails.htm. The feature to share file with a specific user will be available in this API by the end of the month.

You can find the complete documentation at http://dev.onedrive.com. This API is currently in preview, and general availability is planned to happen before the end of the year. Please note that all new features and fixes are being added to the v2 API.

Comment: To add to Ketaki's answer, this applies to both accessing the functionality via the OneDrive for Business endpoint or the Office 365 unified API.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this helps me out a lot! Could you include a source or roadmap for the file-sharing?

Comment: Support for sharing with specific users as well as creating a sharing link will be available in the API by early-Nov.